# Getting a PHP PDO connection from a mysql_connect()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a legacy PHP/MySQL app that calls mysql_connect(). Tons of existing downstream code makes `mysql_query()` calls, either directly or through wrappers, using this connection.

For new code that I develop on the app, I would like to start using PDO.

If I make a PDO connection using the same host/user/pass/dbname credentials, might I be so lucky that under the hood, PHP will re-use the original connection? Or will PHP create two distinct connections to the server (undesirable, albeit totally understandable)?

Thanks!

Comment: @Pascal, @VolkerK: Thanks for the excellent answers, even though the  news is not what I wanted to hear...  ;-(

Sure wish I could accept them both. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using two different APIs (i.e. `mysql_*` and PDO), PHP will generate two different connections.

And, as a "proof", consider this portion of code :

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql://@localhost/astralblog', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
sleep(5);
```

Running this will cause two distinct connections, on the MySQL server -- which will sleep for 5 seconds :

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User       | Host            | db         | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 41 | astralblog | localhost:46551 | astralblog | Sleep   |  188 |       | NULL             |
| 42 | astralblog | localhost:46552 | astralblog | Sleep   |  188 |       | NULL             |
| 43 | astralblog | localhost       | astralblog | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
| 64 | astralblog | localhost       | NULL       | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
| 65 | astralblog | localhost       | NULL       | Sleep   |    4 |       | NULL             |
+----+------------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

*(The connections in question are the two last one, which appeared when I started the PHP script, and disappeared after 5 seconds)*

Answer (score 8):

Both extensions internally use [EG(persistent_list)](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1024#Heading7) to store the persistent connection handle. But they create different hashes/keys for this list, so they can't find entries of the respective other extension.

The mysql extension creates keys of the form `"mysql_<host&port>_<user>..."` while pdo builds `"PDO:DBH:DSN=<dsn>:<user>:...."`.  The hashes are used almost like array-keys in a php script. (Over-)simplyfied example:

```
function pconnect($host,$user,$pass) {
  global $persistent_list;
  $hashkey = sprintf("extensionname_%s_%s_%s", $host, $user, $pass);
  if ( isset($persistent_list[$hashkey]) ) {
    // use stored connection
  }
  else {
    // create new connection
  }
}
```

So the answer is: No, the connections will not be shared between and re-used by the mysql extension and PDO.

Comment: I have to ask, is there a way to share the connections? because i need it for transactions with use paralel the PDO and mysql_connect calls... legacy code problem...

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible without modifying the code of the pdo/mysql modules.