# Wordpress already installed when trying to use it in Zend Framework

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

I followed this solution to including Wordpress functionality within ZF: [Zend Framework and Wordpress integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011670/zend-framework-and-wordpress-integration)

Specifically this code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once 'wp-blog-header.php';
```

I've stepped through the debugger and everything seems to run smoothly, it runs through the is_blog_installed() wordpress function a few times, but then all of a sudden decides the blog is not actually installed and takes me to the "Wordpress is already installed" screen.

Let me know if any files might help in resolving this.

Cheers
Ant

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I kept trying out different options and found that by putting the code above in index.php file, and adding:

```
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public_html/articles/wordpress'),
```

to my include_path helped, but I also had to change my siteurl in wordpress options to include the wordpress sub directory, for some reason this was incorrectly set.

Considering there were two unknown factors contributing to this problem I don't think it would've been possible for someone to troubleshoot with the small amount of information given.

Future questions will be given more thought. apologies.