# Include wordpress latest posts in zend framework?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

I'm trying to include latest posts from wordperss into a zend app. I followed this post [Zend Framework and Wordpress integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011670/zend-framework-and-wordpress-integration) but it's redirecting to a registration disabled page.

My wordpress is installed in /var/www

Zend is in /var/www/account

I use wordpress as the front end and /account is a user area custom zend project. I also have wordpress multisite enabled.