# How do i redirect domain (e.g. example.com) to subdirectory example.com/data/ in AWS Route53

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lamp, amazon-route53

I have LAMP stack setup on ec2 instance and bind it with a custom domain using AWS Route 53 hosted zone. e.g. example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Now i want to redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com to a subdirectory path e.g. example.com/blog.

I tried to setup a static website hosting at S3 and used redirection rule but it doesn't work.
Can someone please help here. I am totally stuck....

Thansk
Deepak

Comment: Try to point domain to the sub folder in apache2 conf as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307047/different-folder-as-website-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Try using an an Application Load Balancer for serving traffic to the ec2 instance and utilise listener rules for redirecting traffic to desired paths. You can take reference from here - https://towardsaws.com/utilising-listener-rules-for-load-balancing-using-aws-application-load-balancer-8e090e0ba469