# how to access mysql link connection resource from zend mysql DB connection object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Here is how i am creating the zend db connection

```
$DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array("host" => "localhost","username" => "root", "password" => "admin123", "dbname" => "user_management"));
```

The problem i have is that in my model files mysql_query have been used to run queries. I want to pass the DB connection  from the controller to the model. How do i get the php factory mysql link resource directly from the zend db connection object.

PS: I have tried adding

```
$db = $DB->getConnection();
```

This isnt working, I think it maybe because of some include file missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to open the connection by application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbtest"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

If you're using Zend Framework 1.8+ (and if you use `resources.db` in application.ini), you can get an instance of db Adapter through Zend_Db_Table everywhere:

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mysql_connect()` returns a different db connection than the PDO adapter. See:

[Getting a PHP PDO connection from a mysql_connect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316413/getting-a-php-pdo-connection-from-a-mysql-connect)

Perhaps you can use the Mysqli adapter rather than the PDO MySQL adapter?