# Using PHP PDO in an existing (legacy) application. Multiple SQL connections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been tasked to write a bunch of extensions to an existing legacy PHP app. The original app is... erm... quite bad. It's 125K lines of spaghetti code littered with raw SQL statements and using the `mysql_*` functions. Every day I find things that really belong on TheDailyWTF. My plan so far is to keep my new code as separate as possible from the legacy code. For database access, I plan to use [Idiorm and Paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/), two really nice little libraries built on top of PDO.

But how will I handle database connections? Or how does PHP handle them internally? I worry that using PDO, every page call will open two separate connections to the database. One from the legact `mysql_connect()` call and one from PDO. Is that true, or will PHP simply share the same connection in the background? Is there any way to make PDO and the legacy `mysql_*` functions use the same database connection? Does it even matter at all it I opens two connections on every page load (note: the app is not using transactions)?

I'm a little hesitant about going over those 125K lines of spaghetti code and replacing all the `mysql_*` functions with something else. I want to touch the original code as little as possible and not break my brain on it.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Yes. it is true. Nothing to worry about

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Getting a PHP PDO connection from a mysql_connect()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316413/getting-a-php-pdo-connection-from-a-mysql-connect)

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I don't agree it's an exact duplicate. I also want to know it it matters that I use two connections (e.g. impact on resources and performance) or if I should start ripping and replacing in the legacy app.

Comment: I's suggest to stop worrying without a reason. When (if ever) there will be impact on resources and performance, you will have **to profile** your application. And refactor it, based on the profiling results. And only if it says that 2 connections being worst bottleneck, it would be time to touch legacy code. Quite far away from your current point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have two connections, but it's not going to break anything. See the answer to this person asking the very same question:

[Getting a PHP PDO connection from a mysql_connect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316413/getting-a-php-pdo-connection-from-a-mysql-connect)

Comment: Thanks. But aside from not breaking anything, are there any other consequences to having two database connections per page load?

Comment: Not unless you were already averaging (max_connections/2) on the DB server.

Answer (score 0):

Those two extensions won't talk to each other and so you will end with two connections. That would be a hell lot of work and very few would benefit IMO -- only those in your shoes, who can't convert fully.